# Should the Android SKD manager download from the same URL twice?

Tags: android, sdk, download-manager

I have the following in my Android SDK Manager Log:

Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml

Fetched Add-ons List successfully

Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml

Done loading packages.

Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml

**Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, 
reason: Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com**

Fetched Add-ons List successfully

Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml

**Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: IO Unknown Host dl-ssl.google.com**

Done loading packages.

Does it matter that the SDK Manager is downloading twice, but failing the second time?